# What is the difference between the different Hebrew words for sin?

Tags: words, hebrew, sin, parashat-ki-tisa

What is the difference between transgression, iniquity, and sin?

Exodus 34:7:

> נֹשֵׂ֥א עָוֺ֛ן וָפֶ֖שַׁע וְחַטָּאָ֑ה

In the Sefaria translation:

> forgiving iniquity, transgression, and sin

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1422376/jewish/Three-Different-Kinds-of-Sin-214B.htm https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29367/difference-between-%d7%97%d6%b5%d7%98%d6%b0%d7%90-and-%d7%a2%d6%b2%d7%91%d6%b5%d7%a8%d6%b8%d7%94/101936#101936

Comment: Yes the lower link has all the discussion, and is how I learned it too. A Chet is "missing the target", a sin done out of some lower reason like gross carelessness or strong temptation, Aveira is doing it on purpose, fully knowing it is a sin and not caring, but still, for some personal benefit and not rebelliousness, a Pesha is an act of rebellion sinning on purpose to davka anger God

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76977/whats-the-difference-in-the-terms-%d7%a2%d6%b8%d7%95%d6%ba%d7%9f-%d7%a4%d6%bc%d6%b6%d7%a9%d7%81%d6%b7%d7%a2-%d7%97%d6%b7%d7%98%d6%bc%d6%b8%d7%90%d6%b8%d7%94-in-exodus-346-7?rq=1 duplicate

Comment: Sorry about that. That is super helpful, thanks so much!